# Calculating Fourier series using convolution theorem

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, convolution

The problem asked to find a Fourier series in two ways, calculating Fourier series directly, and second using the convolution theorem.

$f(t) = 2π-|t|$ on [-2π, 2π]

The Fourier series I got for the above is:

$f(t) = π + ∑ (4/(k^2*π))[1-cos(kπ)]*cos(k*t/2)$

The Fourier series is correct. However, I am not sure how to calculate Fourier series using convolution theorem to get the same result as above.The question says calculate Fourier series for $X_π(t)$ using convolution theorem.I attempted it but ended up with something completely different.If someone can just give me a hint/recipe I would do calculations by myself.